# Where is the template from the_post_thumbnail()?

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

My content.php is used both for my front page than for my single posts. The problem is that it calls the thumbnail with "the_post_thumbnail()" and the thumbnail returns with a particular width and height (`<img width="308" height="208"...`.

I need to change get a different width and height depending if is_single().

Where is the template for the thumbnail or how can I archive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is a theme that you can edit-- ie. one of your own creation-- [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) accepts an argument for size.

```
the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr );
```

Just give it the size you want, for example:

```
the_post_thumbnail('full');
```